# Modify filefilter

Tags: java, apache-commons, java-io

The below code gives me the file path of the files in a directory that ends with "-path.mp4".But I need to get the file path of the files in a directory that doesn't end with "-path.mp4".

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

File directory = new File(path);
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("*-path.mp4");

File[] files = directory.listFiles(fileFilter);

Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            return Long.compare(f2.lastModified(), f1.lastModified());
        }
    });

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        results.add(file.getName());
    }
}

return results;
```

Comment: 1) Get `allFiles` 2) Get all `*-path.mp4` files 3) Remove all `*-path.mp4` files from `allFiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily write your own `FileFilter` in place of trying to make the `WildcardFileFilter` do something it wasn't meant to do, which is *include* files that match the wildcard(s) ...

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname)
    {
        return ! pathname.getPath().endsWith("-path.mp4");
    }
};
```

This is very specific to your question, but you can see that it could be generalized, by returning true when a `File` does **not** match a regex.

---

In fact, you could just extend and override Apache's WildcardFileFilter — the basic idea is:

```
public class WildcardExclusionFilter extends WildcardFileFilter implements FileFilter
{
    public WildcardExclusionFilter(String glob)
    {
        super(glob);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file)
    {
        // Return the Opposite of what the wildcard file filter returns,
        // to *exclude* matching files and *include* anything else.
        return ! super.accept(file);
    }
}
```

You may want to include more of the possible WildcardFileFilter constructors, and override the other form of their **accept** method, `accept(File dir, String name)` too.